# Traer valor de un select de una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

quiero traerme de una base de datos el valor que esta insertado de un select, lo que es el insert si salio bien si lo guarda en la base de datos pero cuando quiero pasarlo al formulario de nuevo para poder editar la informacion no muestra el valor que esta en la base de datos, tengo una lista donde estan los usuarios y un boton para editar entonces cuando le doy al boton editar me trae los datos de ese usuario de nuevo al formulario pero el que no trae es el del select , este es el campo del formulario del select

```
<select class="form-control" name="estatus" id="" required="" data-error="Ingrese su Año ">
                                <option selected="" hidden="">Estatus Cliente</option> 
                                <option value="activo"> Activo</option> 
                                <option value="inactivo">Inactivo</option> 

                            </select>
```

Y este es el del php donde hago la consulta

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE sha1(ID_CLIENTE) = '".($idreg)."' ";          
            $registros=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)  or mysqli_error($mysqli); 

            $registro = mysqli_fetch_array($registros); 
            if (mysqli_num_rows($registros)>0){

              $idreg =sha1($registro['id_cliente']);
              $nombre_empresa = strtoupper($registro["nombre_empresa"]);

              $estatus = $registro["estatus"]; //Aqui es donde se tendria que traer el dato del select
```

Comment: Revisa el valor de `$idreg`, puede que ese valor lo estés recuperando de forma equivocada, de él depende el filtro del `SELECT`

Comment: @A.Cedano No creo que sea eso, ya que el nombre de la empresa si se lo trae de la base de datos.

Comment: Explica mejor tu contexto. ¿Estás lanzando dos acciones distintas desde un mismo formulario/archivo?